# When unit testing, is it good practice to mock the dependencies of the test object when you don't need to?

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mockito, standards

As an example, let's look at 3 classes:

B

C

A(B,C)

So A has a dependency on B and C. If B and C have already been unit tested - when writing unit tests for A is it considered good practice to create the test object A with mocked objects of B and C if you don't need to?

Comment: "Unit" testing _means_ testing `A` in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Yes it's considered good practice as Objects B and C are created in class A for a reason and we want to ensure class A handles the interaction properly.

---

In a unit test you'll want to test the class the unit test is for. So you do not wish to test the functionality of classes B and C in the unit test for class A. However, we can assume class A will do something meaningful with its instances of classes B and C, otherwise they would not have been required in the constructor of class A. That's why you mock them: to either test whether the purpose of these instances has been fulfilled or to allow you to test the conditionals in your class. In other words: does your class handle the interaction with its dependencies properly?

To make these concepts a bit more clear, I've written some psuedocode below. I've written this with Mockito in mind, but another unit testing framework will work just fine:

```java
public class A {

  private final RepositoryB repositoryB;
  private final HelperC helperC;

  @Inject
  public A(RepositoryB repositoryB, HelperC helperC){
    this.repositoryB = repositoryB;
    this.helperC = helperC;
  }

  public List<ObjectD> performATask(boolean doSomeMagic){
    List<ObjectD> ds = repositoryB.getAll();

    if(doSomeMagic){
      helperC.doSomeMagic(ds);
    }

    return ds;
  }
}
```

```java
public class ATest {

  @Rule
  public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

  @Mock
  private RepositoryB repositoryB;

  @Mock
  private HelperC helperC;
  
  @InjectMocks
  private A a;

  @Test
  public performATask_CallMethodWithNoMagic_MuggleListIsReturned(){
    List<ObjectD> ds = a.performATask(false);

    Mockito.verify(repositoryB).getAll();
    Mockito.verifyNoInteractions(helperC);
  }

  @Test
  public performATask_CallMethodWithMagic_MagicalListIsReturned(){
    Mockito.when(repositoryB.getAll()).thenReturn(createMuggleTestList());

    List<ObjectD> ds = a.performATask(true);

    Mockito.verify(repositoryB).getAll();
    Mockito.verify(helperC).doSomeMagic(anyList());
  }

  private List<ObjectD> createMuggleTestList(){
    // Create it!
  }
}
```

What you see here is that class A indeed has a dependency on classes B (RepositoryB) and C (HelperC). In class A you can see that class RepositoryB is used to retrieve data from the database. The data is returned as a List. Based on the boolean argument passed, HelperC will or will not perform some magic on the retrieved data. We don't care what magic it does, only that it happends based on the boolean argument. Likewise we don't care how RepositoryB retrieves its data from the database. That's the worry of the unit tests of those respective classes. What we want to know is: does class A still call the RepositoryB.getAll and does or does it not call helperC.doSomeMagic?

The first unit test tests if only RepositoryB.getAll is called (and HelperC completely ignored) if performATask(false) is called. The second unit test tests if RepositoryB.getAll is called as well as HelperC.doSomeMagic if performATask(true) is called. Also note that the RepositoryB mock is used to return a test list using Mockito.when(). This is important in the second unit test:

Calling a mock method will not actually do anything; it's a mock, after all. But if in the second unit test HelperC.doSomeMagic is called, the verify on HelperC expects a List. This makes sense as you want to ensure HelperC.doSomeMagic is always called with a List and not something else (such as null), as that's the desirable behaviour for class A. However RepositoryB.getAll() will - if RepositoryB is a mock - not return anything, so null will be returned. This verify would then fail (and thus your unit test will fail, rightfully so):

`Mockito.verify(helperC).doSomeMagic(anyList());`
It expects a list to be passed to doSomeMagic, not null.

So the mock is also used to return a List under certain conditions. (In this case Mockito.when is used to return a test list, created in the unit test.)